# how to increase processing speed while gaining data from a database?

Tags: sql, image-processing, postgresql-9.2, arcmap, arcgis-server

we are creating a website which shows temperature datas (max temp, min temp, avg temp) of a month for a particular district within a country.

For this purpose we have created a single database file which consists of all (raster) datas For each month within the year range (1975-2013). The datas are saved into a single .mxd file.
We have published this file into the webserver.

Will creating a single db file slow down the processing speed, if multiple users try to access different (temperature) datas at the same time???(because we have a single DB file)

If so, ***is their any possible solutions for the same?***

PS:- We have created the db such that the (monthly)datas are saved in a sequential format.

Answer (score 1):

There are two elements that help in retrieving the data :

1. The request send to the web-server.
2. The back-end algorithm which retrieves the data.

As the number of users increases the web-server has to handle that many requests and for each request a query will be generated.

So by dividing the data into different parts wont help in reducing the time of generating the query.
Second thing is the query being executed. Now dividing the database will significantly help in executing the query.

For eg. if the user queries for 14th march in year 2004 then by dividing the database based on year or month you can SIGNIFICANTLY reduce the time required for the search.